# Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. 2021 Not Async

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

getting this error:

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

```
const MapBox = () => {
  const mapContainer = useRef(null);
  const map = useRef(null);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
  const onClick = () => setVisible(true);
  const closeHandler = () => {
    setVisible(false);
  }
useEffect(() => {
  }, [visible])


return (
  <>
    <MapContainer ref={mapContainer} className="map-container" onClick={onClick}></MapContainer>
    <ModalContainer visible={visible} closeHandler={closeHandler} />
  </>
)
}
```

The modal container is just a simple modal pop, only returning a jsx component. That only shows if visible is true, and if runs closeHandler is a button is pressed.

```
const ModalContainer = ({ visible, closeHandler }) => {
  useEffect(() => {}, [visible])
  return (
    <>
      {visible && (
        <div>
          <Modal
            closeButton
            aria-labelledby="modal-title"
            open={visible}
            onClose={closeHandler}
          >
            <Modal.Header>
              <Text id="modal-title" size={18}>
                Welcome to
                <Text b size={18}>
                  NextUI
                </Text>
              </Text>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
              <Input
                clearable
                bordered
                fullWidth
                color="primary"
                size="large"
                placeholder="Email"
              />
              <Input
                clearable
                bordered
                fullWidth
                color="primary"
                size="large"
                placeholder="Password"
              />
              <Row justify="space-between">
                <Checkbox>
                  <Text size={14}>
                    Remember me
                  </Text>
                </Checkbox>
                <Text size={14}>
                  Forgot password?
                </Text>
              </Row>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button auto flat color="error" onClick={closeHandler}>
                Close
              </Button>
              <Button auto onClick={closeHandler}>
                Sign in
              </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal>
        </div>)
      }
    </>
  );
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, all other people on here with this error message are running async code etc. This one is a lot simpler and the error only comes up the first time the click to close event happens.

Comment: What happens in the `useEffect` ? And you will most likely have to show us the `ModalContainer` code too

Comment: Added it now, thanks